# selecting the max values based on a count

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i retrieve the max of each ValueCount based on the firmid.  I need the data to be output like so.

My code is below

```
SELECT
 F.FirmID,
 F.Name,
 DL.ValueId,
 DL.ValueName,
 count(DL.ValueName) AS ValueCount
 FROM 
dbo.Jobs AS J
 INNER JOIN DimensionValues AS DV ON
DV.CrossRef = J.JobId
 INNER JOIN dbo.DimensionLists AS DL ON
DV.ValueId = DL.ValueId
 INNER JOIN Firms AS F ON
F.FirmId =  J.ClientFirmId
 WHERE
DL.DimensionId = 4
  GROUP BY
F.FirmID,
F.Name,
DL.ValueName,
DL.ValueId
```

this produces something like

```
firmid | value | count
1        1       5
1        2       10
2        3       1
2        1       6
```

i need to return back the records with 10 and 6.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What's not working?

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli it works fine, but returns all the rows.  I want it to return only the rows with the max count based on the firmid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT : *SQL 2005 answer deleted.***

Then you could push your results into a temporary table (or table variable) and do something like this...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TempTable
WHERE
  ValueCount = (SELECT MAX(ValueCount) FROM TempTable AS Lookup WHERE FirmID = TempTable.FirmID)
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TempTable
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT FirmID, MAX(ValueCount) AS ValueCount FROM TempTable GROUP BY FirmID) AS lookup
    ON  lookup.FirmID     = TempTable.FirmID
    AND lookup.ValueCount = TempTable.ValueCount
```

These will give multiple records if any ValueCount is tied with another for the same FirmID.  As such, you could try this...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TempTable
WHERE
  value = (
            SELECT TOP 1
              value
            FROM
              TempTable as lookup
            WHERE
              FirmID = TempTable.FirmID
            ORDER BY
              ValueCount DESC
          )
```

Comment: that doesnt compile.  Its an old sql2000 server we are migrating data from

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you need to produce the result set of the query in order to determine the Max ValueCount, then you need to do the query again to pull just the records with Max ValueCount. You can do this many way, like repeating the main query as subqueries, and in SQL Server 2005/2008 by using a CTE. I think using the subqueries gets a little messy and would prefer the CTE, but for SQL Server 2000 you don't have that as an option. So, I've used a temp table instead of a CTE. I run it once to get the MaxValueCount and save that into a temp table, then run the query again and join against the temp table to get just the record with MaxValueCount.

```
create table #tempMax
(
    FirmID int,
    MaxValueCount int
)

insert #tempMax
SELECT t.FirmID, MAX(t.ValueCount) AS MaxValueCount
  FROM (
SELECT F.FirmID, F.Name, DL.ValueId, DL.ValueName
     , count(DL.ValueName) AS ValueCount
  FROM dbo.Jobs AS J
 INNER JOIN DimensionValues AS DV ON DV.CrossRef = J.JobId
 INNER JOIN dbo.DimensionLists AS DL ON DV.ValueId = DL.ValueId
 INNER JOIN Firms AS F ON F.FirmId =  J.ClientFirmId
 WHERE DL.DimensionId = 4 
 GROUP BY F.FirmID, F.Name, DL.ValueName, DL.ValueId) t

SELECT t.FirmID, t.Name, t.ValueID, t.ValueName, t.ValueCount
  FROM (
SELECT F.FirmID, F.Name, DL.ValueId, DL.ValueName
     , count(DL.ValueName) AS ValueCount
  FROM dbo.Jobs AS J
 INNER JOIN DimensionValues AS DV ON DV.CrossRef = J.JobId
 INNER JOIN dbo.DimensionLists AS DL ON DV.ValueId = DL.ValueId
 INNER JOIN Firms AS F ON F.FirmId =  J.ClientFirmId
 WHERE DL.DimensionId = 4 
 GROUP BY F.FirmID, F.Name, DL.ValueName, DL.ValueId) t
 INNER JOIN #tempMax m ON t.FirmID = m.FirmID and t.ValueCount = m.MaxValueCount

DROP TABLE #tempMax
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a derived table for this:

```
SELECT  F.FirmID, 
        F.Name, 
        DL.ValueId, 
        DL.ValueName, 
        T.ValueCount    

FROM    Jobs J
        INNER JOIN DimensionValues DV
            ON DV.Crossref = J.JobID
        INNER JOIN DimensionList DL
            ON DV.ValueID = DL.ValueID
        INNER JOIN Firms F
            ON F.FirmID = J.ClientFirmID

        --derived table
        INNER JOIN (SELECT FirmID, MAX(ValueName) ValueCount FROM DimensionList GROUP BY FirmID) T
            ON T.FirmID = F.FirmID

WHERE  DL.DimensionId = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

TBL1 and TBL2 is your query:

SELECT *
FROM TBL1
WHERE
TBL1.ValueCount = (SELECT MAX(TBL2.ValueCount) FROM TBL2 WHERE TBL2.FIRMID = TBL1.FIRMID)